# Breezejs + Web API OData Concurrency issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, odata, breeze

I have a Single Page Web Application built with Durandal and Breeze 1.5 client talking to Aspnet Web API OData services which in turn uses Entity Framework 5 to access a SQL Server database.

The OData services use v3.0 of the OData protocol

The issue I have is with getting concurrency checks to happen, the EF module makes use of model properties which, in the mapping, are identified as optimistic concurrency tokens

The problem occurs when an entity on the client has one or more properties updated and then saved via Breeze - it sends the update as a HTTP PATCH operation including only the properties that have been updated - this does not include the original value of the column used as a concurrency token and so any concurrency error is not identified when the EF context calls save changes.

How can I configure Breeze to send updates via the PUT verb including the complete entity or get it to always include the original value of the concurrency column?

Comment: AFAIK you can use Breeze.js to perform POST and GETs right now, I have not tried doing puts.  You may try including Breeze.ajaxpost.js and switching the call to a PUT or something and seeing if you can properly extend the AJAX call to meet your needs.  ---   http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs

Comment: OData is great for querying but not so great for saves.  Can you user Web API without OData?  Breeze saves work better that way.